# Add something to hash value if key exists?

Tags: ruby, hash, hashmap

I have a Hash in Ruby:

```
hash = Hash.new
```

It has some key value pairs in it, say:

```
hash[1] = "One"
hash[2] = "Two"
```

If the hash contains a key `2`, then I want to add "Bananas" to its value. If the hash doesn't have a key `2`, I want to create a new key value pair `2=>"Bananas"`.

I know I can do this by first checkng whether the hash has the key `2` by using `has_key?` and then act accordingly. But this requires an `if` statement and more than one line.

So is there a simple, elegant one-liner for achieving this?

Comment: And what code have you written toward solving this?

Comment: Something to understand about coding: Writing code that only takes one line isn't the goal. The goal is to write code that is "elegant", which mean understandable and powerful, not necessarily "terse". A simple conditional and modification in two or three lines is perfectly good if it's readable and accomplishes what you need. You'll find the programming world is full of three-line versions of what you're asking, simply because it is readable and just as fast.

Comment: Ruby allows semicolons instead of line breaks. You can write *everything* in one line, just by replacing line breaks with semicolons. Problem solved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works:

```
hash[2] = (hash[2] || '') + 'Bananas'
```

If you want all keys to behave this way, you could use the "default" feature of Ruby's Hash:

```
hash = {}
hash.default_proc = proc { '' }
hash[2] += 'Bananas'
```

Comment: Thank you or your answer, I'll accept it as soon as I can. Though I don't really understand: What does the (hash[2]||'') part mean

Comment: If `hash[2]` returns a value it's "truthy", which satisfies the `||` (boolean OR). If `hash[2]` does not have a value, `nil` is returned, which is "falsey" causing `||` to fire off, and return `""`. Which is the exact reason I commented above that a three-line version is more readable. Using Boolean logic this way is an advanced technique we use at the cost of readability.

Comment: The `default=` method with a mutable object is a bug waiting to happen:`hash[3]<<"pinapple"; p h[4] #=>"pineapple"`

Comment: @sttenslag, you're right.  I changed the answer to use `default_proc` instead so you generate a new string each time.  Another interesting option would be `hash.default = ''.freeze`.

Comment: It might be worth adding to the answer why you are using `default_proc=` instead of `default=`, for those who don't read the comments.

Answer (score 5):

You could set the default value of the hash to an empty string, then make use of the << operator to concat whatever new values are passed:

```
h = Hash.new("")
#=> {}
h[2] << "Bananas"
#=> "Bananas" 
h
#=> {2=>"Bananas"} 
h[2] << "Bananas"
#=> "BananasBananas"
```

Per @rodrigo.garcia's comment, another side effect of this approach is that `Hash.new()` sets the default return value for the hash (which may or may not be what you want). In the example above, that default value is an empty string, but it doesn't have to be:

```
h2 = Hash.new(2)
#=> {}
h2[5] 
#=> 2
```

Comment: `a += b`, being equivalent to `a = a + b` is less efficient than `<<` or `concat` because it creates a copy of the string. The others will "really" append to the existing string. Other than that I think your solution is the best :)

Comment: Ah yes, that's a great point. Thanks for the comment, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Using `Hash.new(x)` will always return the same instance `x` as the default value. Since here you are modifying `""` by concatenating `"Bananas"` to it twice, now every unset key will return `"BananasBananas"` (try doing `h[4]` for example). This might be the desired behavior in some cases, but you should explain it in your answer.

Comment: @rodrigo.garcia - added a note.

Answer (score 4):

```
(hash[2] ||= "").concat("Bananas")
```

Comment: `<<` is just an alias for `concat`

Comment: @p11y They do have differences also.. But that's not the point here..  :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit can't imagine that there would be a difference, since the both call `rb_str_concat` internally. It's really just an alias

Comment: @p11y For you only. Here we go `irb(main):001:0> a = []
=> []
irb(main):002:0> a << [1,2]
=> [[1, 2]]
irb(main):003:0> a = []
=> []
irb(main):004:0> a.concat [1,2]
=> [1, 2]
irb(main):005:0>` So `#<<` don't splat , but `#concat` does. That's the difference only I have seen in my learning.

Comment: But what you show is an Array, not a String. On the Array class `<<` is an alias for `push`. Confusing, I admit. Here, we are operating on a String.

Comment: @Stefan I like that.. same I requested to *sawa* also.

Comment: @p11y That's why I told *But that's not the point here...*.. :-) And the same reason I wouldn't agree *`<<` is just an alias for `concat`*

Comment: @ArupRakshit ah sorry now I see :) Just wanted to say that of course one could also use `<<`

Comment: @ArupRakshit Well then I must disagree again :) On the String class `<<` is an alias for `concat`. On the Array class, `<<` is an alias for `push`. Just because the methods have the same name doesn't mean they have anything to do with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, both your roads lead to the same place. So `Hash[2] = "bananas"` produces the same result as first checking the hash for key 2. However, if you actually need the process of checking the hash for some reason a way to do that is use the `.has_key?` method, and a basic `if` conditional.

Suppose there is a hash,

```
`Hash = { 1 => "One", 2 => "Two" }`
```

setup a block of code based on the truth-value of a key search,

`if hash.has_key?(2) == true
   hash[2] = "bananas"
else
   hash[2] = "bananas"
end`

or more simply,

`hash.has_key?(2) == true ? hash[2] = "bananas" : hash[2] = "bananas"`

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise the hash with a block and then directly concatenate:

```
hash = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = ""}
hash[1] << "One"
hash[2] << "Two"
hash[2] << "Bananas"

{1=>"One", 2=>"TwoBananas"}
```